# Slide to unlock appears even when pattern lock is activated. How can I get straight to pattern lock mode after screen is turned on?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, lock-screens

I thought the whole idea of pattern lock is to replace the 'slide to unlock' thing with something safe. Well I don't know if this is a bug or not but I have to 'slide to unlock' first before I can use my set pattern to unlock the phone (the epitome of redundancy). How do I get straight to pattern unlock after turning on the screen?.

By the way I own an Xperia Neo V running Sony's skin, Timescape UI

Comment: That is a bug indeed. Are you using something like GO Locker or any other third party app about locking the device?

Comment: Nope stock locker

Comment: @RodrigoGuedes - are you sure this is a bug?  My HTCs have all worked in a similar way, the slide to unlock (or pull up a ring) is always there, with security after that.  It stops you failing the code in your pocket and locking yourself out of the device.

Comment: I too have a HTC One S and when I set a pattern, the lock ring is also required first. cjk may have the correct explanation for that, but I don't recall any mention of some sort of maximum number of tries for the pattern, so yes it is indeed quite annoying. I guess **screen lock** and **device lock** are seperate things....

Comment: @cjk Actually I choose poorly my words, I'm sorry. I'm not really sure if it's a bug but I'm almost sure. That's because I have a device (Galaxy SII) with the same OS (Android) and version (2.3) and there is no such kind of redundancy.

Comment: @rodrigoguedes Android unfortunately isn't ubiquitous across devices, different skins can change the UI in many ways, so Samsung, HTC and Sony will all be different, and it only Nexus devices showing true Android. Your options to fix are to root and apply a different ROM, or to find a different lock screen that can override the Sony one and also be turned off.

Answer (score 2):

Are you running a custom ROM?

I know that in cyanogenmod you can choose to keep the slide to unlock screen and then your unlock pattern. That's the way mine is set up.

To turn this off (in cyanogenmod 7's case) follow these steps

1. Go to settings
2. Tap Cyanogenmod settings
3. Tap Lockscreen
4. Tap Unlock options
5. Then uncheck the top option labelled "Skip on security"

You might be able to find the "Skip on security" setting somewhere else on your phone if you aren't running an official version of cyanogenmod or if the rom is only based on cyanogenmod

Comment: I believe this setting (or equivalent) is now called something like "Directly show pattern".