# Why I need swipe screen before enter pattern?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, locked-out, pattern-lock

I use Android 6.0.1 (Samsung S7).
Phone locked by pattern. But to unlock it I need swipe screen first, and enter pattern code after that.
I don't have this problem(features) on s4 Android 5.0.1.

How disable this swipe ?
Thnx

Comment: See http://android.stackexchange.com/q/30709/1465

Answer (score -1):

I found solution for me - it is use finger sensor. To unlock phone - click home button and leave finger on it. (Sensor integrated in home button). And no need to enter pattern, but if want unlock with pattern need swipe.(If phone use somebody else)